# Respecting an API key with Amazon's API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless

I'm learning serverless applications. I've created a simple Lambda that I've confirmed is working via Paw/curl.

Next I completed the API Gateway tasks of:

- create a POST Resource that requires an API key
- create beta and test Stages
- create the API key
- create a Usage Plan
- associate the API key with the Usage Plan
- associate the Usage Plan with the test Stage

I expect requests with the `x-api-key` Header to work, and those without to be denied. But I observe all requests continue to successfully finish regardless of that Header's presence.

I've recreated individual API Gateway steps and eventually the process as a whole, to no avail. Any clue of what I've missed?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything that screams of a problem. [This blog](https://datanextsolutions.com/blog/protect-aws-api-gateway-endpoints-using-api-keys/) walks through doing the same thing, but it results in a 403 when calling without the key. Any chance it's something simple, like you changed the "API key required" flag and didn't deploy again?

Comment: You can confirm the API Keys and Usage Plans are set up correctly by clicking on Stages -> "stage name" -> "resource name" (not the method, the resource path). You should see a rectangle that says "Authorization: NONE, API Key: Required". Do you see that on your stage?

Comment: @JasonWadsworth, You called it! I updated the flag but hadn't redeployed and that did the trick. Thanks for taking a look; post that as an answer for the win.

Comment: Thank you @tankthinks for showing me how to confirm the setup. I followed your steps before (key wasn't required) and after (key required) my redeploy. Exciting times!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not seeing anything that screams of a problem. This blog walks through doing the same thing, but it results in a 403 when calling without the key. Any chance it's something simple, like you changed the "API key required" flag and didn't deploy again?